# XAML: How can I target the same property twice within a storyboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp-xaml

I am building a 3D Cube with 3 different view-able sides. I want to represent a choice to the user that can be displayed in 3 different ways. For example, I want to give the user a choice to pick a language. So I want one side of the cube to be the English flag and after a few seconds, it flips to an image of the text "English" and after a few seconds, that image flips to another image signifying the English Language choice(maybe the Australian flag).

I have created a storyboard animation for that. Pseudo-code for that is

```
   Storyboard{
    MakeImage1Visible();----Problem part A
    RotateImage1By90degrees();
    MakeImage1NotVisible();----Problem part B
    MakeImage2Visible();
    RotateImage2ByMinus90degrees();
//Do the same for the transition between Image2 and Image 3
    }
```

My issue is that this pseudocode forces me to target the same property twice within a storyboard(in problem part A and in problem Part B).

And VS doesn't allow that.

I know I can make multiple storyboards and call them from the code-behind with a timer every few seconds. This is ugly. Is there any more elegant solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What application did you created, wpf or uwp?

Comment: UWP but if you have a solution in WPF, please let me know